# turn textarea values into python list

Tags: python, django

I am working on turning textarea value into a list.

this is my example value:

I am thinking separated by commas would be good like this.

```
fred, debbie, dale, mitch, tintin, denmark
```

and i want to make it python list list

```
memberList = ['fred', 'debbie', 'dale', 'mitch', 'tintin', 'denmark']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
value = 'fred, debbie, dale, mitch, tintin, denmark'
memberList = value.split(',')
```

Comment: Thanks it really helps